# How do I set my Peavy VYPYR to get the best sound from my Boss ME-25?

Tags: amplifiers, guitar-effects, effects-pedal

I followed what Boss says and set the tone to 0. I'm using a clean channel on the amp. I'm close to what it should be I'm just a hair away and I think the problem is with the settings on the amp such as gain or mid or something else I'm not sure. I'm getting a muffled sound is the only way I can describe it. Weather I have it set to play metal or blues it doesnt get that crisp sound. It's almost there but something is off I'm trying to hard so I'm missing it I think that's why I'm asking. Any ideas or hints could help a lot.